# write to log during debugging in visual c++ express 2010

Tags: visual-c++, ide

I am working on a GUI project in Visual C++ Express 2010. Now working on the classes, and to test them I do not want to start working in the GUI already. Is there a way to send some debug output to a log file or the debuggers output window?

Have done quite some work in Appcelerator's Titanium lately, and there you can use `Ti.API.info()` to send some info to yourself, to see how the app is behaving. Is there something for Visual C++ too?

Thanks!
Pieter

Comment: Consider putting all of your library code into a library.  Then you'll be able to use simple console application projects to test it out, your code will be easier to unit test, etc., etc.

Comment: That is a good idea in the beginning, but may be less useful once you are working in the GUI (and still need it there).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `TRACE` [macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6w95a4ha.aspx) - they will send the output to the debug output window. You can also see the trace messages without the debugger running using  [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647)

See also [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sx52ww7.aspx) for an overview of the available debugging / tracing techniques.

Answer (score 0):

Did a little research more research with Google using TRACE as a keyword. Ended up [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815787) with a solution that did exactly what I wanted.

```
using namespace System::Diagnostics;
Debug::WriteLine("This will be written to debug output");
```

Now, start debugging, go the the "Output" tab in the Output window and show output from "Debug". Then it will give you the messages I was looking for. So `Debug::WriteLine` is what I needed here.

Comment: Ah, you're clearly using C++/CLI and targeting the .NET Framework. That's important information to put into your question. This is not plain old C++.